# React Native - AppRegistry.registerComponent com Provider

Tags: react, react-native, redux

Gostaria de saber o por que de quando eu uso o provider assim

```
//Root.js
import React from 'react';
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux"
import { listaDesejosList, listaDesejosEdit } from "./src/reducers/reducers"
import customMiddleware from "./src/commons/custom-middleware"
import App from "./App"
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    listaDesejos: listaDesejosList,
    desejo: listaDesejosEdit
})
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(customMiddleware))

const Root = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    )
}
export default Root;
```

E tento usar no registerComponent assim:

```
//index.js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Root from './Root';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, <App/>);
```

Ocorre esse erro

```
could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a `<Provider>`
```

Pergunto pois estou fazendo um app em reactjs e react native e gostaria de manter um certo padrão no código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iae, eu tenho um código pronto e funciona perfeitamente.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './store/reducers/index';
import Navigation from './Navigation'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Navigation />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

E no meu index.js eu chamo da seguinte maneira.

```
import React from 'react'
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import App from './app/App';

const MyApp = props => (
    <App />
)

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => MyApp)
```

Os meus reducers e as minhas actions estão em outra pasta, para deixar mais organizado.